# Delimit os.walk to look only files and not directories

Tags: python, os.walk

I have a little question, I have a directorie which contain directories  (with files in it) and files. Can i use os.walk to treat files 1 by 1 but not the files into directories ?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to only list the files in the highest level dir without going in to sub-dirs? os.listdir should do it for you.

You can easily add a check to skip dirs this way

```
 for f in os.listdir(path):
     if f.is_dir():
         continue
     print f
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
os.walk("/path/to/dir").next()[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well for exemple i have a directorie like that:

boite_noire/
.....helloworld/
.....test1.txt
.....test2.txt

I would like somethink like that at the end of the script:
boite_noire/
.....helloworld/
.....test1/
.....test2/

And in the test1 dirctorie I put test1.txt and same for test2.

I tried listdir but without success and yes os.walk.next()[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbGww.png) should be a good idea cause my problem is when i run my script my os.walk scan the directories and files inside and i don't want to, i only want him to scan the files at the source.

My code with os.walk
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbGww.png)

Answer (score 0):

My code with os.listdir:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfCx3.png)

I think there is something easier for both but i don't know what :/